# Break Symmetric-Key Algo When Secret Key Is Known?

Tags: cryptography, symmetric-key

Suppose I have a super simple symmetric-key algorithm, and by super simple I mean it's a straight-up extension of the Caesar Cipher.

If I were to provide ciphertext *AND* the secret key that was used to encrypt it, what would be the expected probability of someone decrypting it?

I understand the math behind the calculations when the key is secret, but what about if the key *is* known? Should a typical computer be expected to break it within a reasonable timeframe?

I looked at different symmetric-key breaking techniques but I don't believe any of them will be able to break this algorithm *even* if the secret key is known. Hence my confusion and the question.

Comment: This problem statement makes no sense. If one has the key and the algorithm then one just decrypts the ciphertext normally.

Comment: I've tried my best to answer the question from a variety of angles as a nice gesture, but this question really belongs in https://crypto.stackexchange.com/ , and with more context. And realistically, whatever algorithm you invented is either [already known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) or [extremely insecure](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/topics/cryptography/the-dangers-of-rolling-your-own-encryption/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. btw, it's not OTP, either, I can encrypt any number of million-character snippets with word BANANA and I claim that there's no way to decrypt them :)

Comment: Then write a paper on it, or at least post it on github. And no, "we couldn't figure out what's your algorithm based on ciphertext/secret pairs" is not evidence that the algorithm will be good in keeping secrets hidden. It only shows that its working are unexpected.

Comment: Absolutely, I agree 100%, one doesn't prove the other, and what I'm describing may not even be a necessary condition for a secure algorithm. But I thought this would be a good first step in determining whether the algorithm is valid at all - can it be reverse-engineered given the output and the key. I appreciate the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern cryptography is based on [Kerckhoffs's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle), where we assume that "the enemy knows the system". That means we assume the algorithm and ciphertext are known, and only the secret key is unknown.

If you give the secret key to the enemy, they know everything. They can just run the decrypt function and get the plaintext.

And while it's unclear in your question, I *think* you meant to ask "what if we hide the algorithm?" So instead of making the secret key unknown, what if the algorithm was unknown?

This poses two problems. First, it's really hard to make a secure encryption algorithm, and you can't collaborate on a secret algorithm, so whatever you have is probably insecure by itself. Maybe it can be broken with [frequency analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis) without ever looking at the secret key, for example.

And second, the recipient of the message must also know the algorithm. So you must securely transfer the algorithm from the sender to the recipient. If you have that capability, why are you not using it to send your message in the first place?

Regarding how difficulty it is to guess an algorithm, that totally depends on how much you "extended" it, and how many ciphertext/secret keys/plaintexts the attacker has access to. This is now a case of [Reverse Engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering), not cryptography.

Can you pile up enough transformations to make reverse engineering infeasible? Yes. Will that add security to your system? Kinda. This specific technique is called [Security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity), and is frowned upon due to its high costs and complexity for low security gains.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Just to clarify what I'm after: I understand that eventually only the secret key will be secret, but at the moment I'm just trying to ascertain the validity of the algorithm without revealing it just yet or losing its ownership. How do I do that? The algorithm, again, is super simple - it has a **single** trivial transformation, yet it doesn't suffer from the frequency analysis problem - it produces ciphertexts with fairly even letter distribution frequency, even with spaces and English language articles.

Comment: So my thought process is, if I provide ANY number of ciphertext + secret keys combos and no one can decrypt them then I know the algorithm is unbreakable, meaning, it should be unbreakable under normal circumstances when the secret key is unknown. Should that be the case or does reverse-engineering symmetric-key algorithms (again, knowing that it does a single transformation) whilst knowing the secret key is still a hard/brute force problem?

Comment: Please don't guess what the question asker means.

Comment: @GeorgeUlos: Don't just thank him for the reply, **read it**.

Comment: I read the answer and I believe I clarified points raised in it: how many ciphertexts/secrets does the attacker have access to? UNLIMITED. how many transformations am I piling on? ONE. does it have frequency analysis problem? NO. Am I referring to security by obscurity? NO. Do these answers now affect the probability of reverse-engineering the algorithm? Which was my original question - what is the probability of deducing _simple_ symmetric-key algorithm knowing the ciphertext and the secret key.

Comment: @GeorgeUlos: You do, in fact, seem to be referring to security through obscurity. Read the Kerkchoff's principle page.